# PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in..... with SELECT MAX

Tags: php, mysql

I know there are milions of posts like that on the forum, but none seem to help my issue. Here's the PHP code:

```
  $countsql = "SELECT MAX(id) as count FROM art";
  $count = mysqli_query($link, $countsql);
  if(!$count){
    echo "Error\n";
    echo "Code: ". mysqli_error($link);
    exit;
  }

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count)){ $count = $row["count"]; }

  $ppp = 2;
  $start = $count - (($page-1) * $ppp);
  $end = $count - (($page-1) * 2 * $ppp);
```

The issue appears in the line with the mysqli_fetch_assoc.
Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't throw anything. Or at least nothing appears on the screen

Comment: It probably doesn't make a difference in this case because you're only returning a single row, but `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count)){ $count = $row["count"]; }` it's generally a bad idea to re-use the same variable for your resultset and where you're storing the records from that resultset when you iterate over them

Comment: Although checking for a second iteration when $count is no longer a resultset but a string may cause some problems

Comment: @MarkBaker that's what I was thinking, the problem probably occurs on the second iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count)){ 
   $count = $row["count"]; 
}
```

The second iteration sets `$count` to be a string, making the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` call fail.

Because you only have one row in your resultset, you could change `while` into `if`:

```
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count)){ 
   $count = $row["count"]; 
}
```

Or, even better, don't use the same variable for two (quite distinct) purposes.

```
$count_result = mysqli_query($link, $countsql);
...
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_result)){ 
   $count = $row["count"]; 
}
```